# How to get object value which has a space and a special character in its key and object name with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Below I have a value in one variable called `publicIdentifier`.
Using `console.log("publicIdentifier",publicIdentifier);`
I am getting the value below. I have to get the value of `MSISDN-MSISDN` into differnet variable.
I am getting below request which value is in sting so I am making in JSON and then I am trying to get this MSISDN-MSISDN. Is there any way that I can take it withought making JSON that is also fine . Please help.

```
 request:"{"Storm 1.5 GB":{"SIM Product-SIMType":"MobileSIM","MSISDN Product-MSISDN":"","MSISDN-MSISDN":"9900004681","SIM Product-SIMNumber":"8923401000003155"}}"
publicIdentifier=JSON.parse(request)

Storm 1.5 GB:Object {SIM Product-SIMType: "MobileSIM", MSISDN Product-MSISDN: "", MSISDN-MSISDN: "9900004672", …}
MSISDN Product-MSISDN:""
MSISDN-MSISDN:"9900004672"
SIM Product-SIMNumber:"8923401000003150"
SIM Product-SIMType:"MobileSIM"
```

I tried the code below, but it's not working in node js.

```
publicIdentifier123=publicIdentifier['Storm 1.5 GB']['MSISDN-MSISDN']

 loyaltyOnBoardMember = async (args, publicIdentifier) => {
        //console.log("loyality args ",args.interactionItem[0].item);
        const storm = publicIdentifier["Storm 1.5 GB"];
        Object.keys(storm)
            .forEach(key =>
                console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${publicIdentifier["Storm 1.5 GB"][key]}`));
        const publicIdentifier2 = storm["Storm 1.5 GB"]["MSISDN-MSISDN"];
        console.log("aaaaaaa", publicIdentifier2);
        const value = args.interactionItem[0].item;
        let uri = `${config.dlmUrl}/loyaltyManagement/loyaltyMember/loyaltyOnBoardMember`;
        let contactMedium = [];
        if (_.toLower(value.engagedParty.contactMedium[0].type) === 'mobile') {
            contactMedium.push({
                type: "Mobile",
                medium: {
                    type: "mobile",
                    value: value.engagedParty.contactMedium[0].mediumargs.mobile
                }
            })
        }
        if (_.toLower(value.engagedParty.contactMedium[0].type) === 'emailaddress') {
            contactMedium.push({
                type: "EmailAddress",
                medium: {
                    type: "EmailAddress",
                    value: value.engagedParty.contactMedium[0].medium.emailAddress
                }
            })
        }
        let request = {
            publicIdentifier: publicIdentifier['Storm 1.5 GB MSISDN-MSISDN'],
            name: value.engagedParty.givenName,
            status: value.engagedParty.status,
            validFor: {
                startDateTime: value.createdDate
            },
            characteristic: [
                {
                    name: "businessType",//characteristicName,
                    value: "Postpaid"//characteristicValue
                }
            ],
            engageParty: {
                id: value.engagedParty.id,
                contactMedium: contactMedium
            }
        };

        logger.info(`${uri}`);
        try {
            logger.debug(request);
            const response = await this.post(uri, request, this.options);
            logger.debug(response);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            this.exceptionHandler.handleException(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: publicIdentifier123=publicIdentifier['Storm 1.5 GB MSISDN-MSISDN'] did you try this?

Comment: no.. let me try that also

Comment: this does not seem to be a valid JSON response or YAML! what type of response is this

Comment: Please show the complete code where `publicIdentifier` is declared and its value is set.

Comment: not wokring  just tried

Comment: Rizwan @apena please wait , I'll post comeplete thing what i am trring .

Comment: I have updated my question  , where in request key getting value that is string , so I am making in json and passing in publicIdentifier

Comment: @Rizwan , please review my updated questin and pleas help

Comment: Having space in keys of a json file is not a practice I’ve seen better to use camel or pascal casing

Comment: Then you can access as.  request.key_needed

Comment: I didn't get you , how can I get that value in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work, even without parsing. Perhaps there's some typo in your code?

*edit*: given your edited question I suppose the error is here

```
let request = {
     publicIdentifier: publicIdentifier['Storm 1.5 GB MSISDN-MSISDN'],
//                     ^ should be ...
//                 ... publicIdentifier['Storm 1.5 GB'']['MSISDN-MSISDN'],
```

```js
const someObj = {
  "Storm 1.5 GB": {
    "SIM Product-SIMType":"MobileSIM",
    "MSISDN Product-MSISDN":"",
    "MSISDN-MSISDN":"9900004681",
    "SIM Product-SIMNumber":"8923401000003155" }
};
// the first value
const storm15Gb = someObj["Storm 1.5 GB"];

// check if values can be retrieved, using keys /w spaces/dashes
Object.keys( storm15Gb )
  .forEach( key  => 
    console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${someObj["Storm 1.5 GB"][key]}`) );

// to be sure
const publicIdentifier = someObj["Storm 1.5 GB"]["MSISDN-MSISDN"];
console.log(publicIdentifier);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Please see my updated question , I tried that alos but not workig